# Find out if asked for a password when looping over hosts using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I am looping over a number of hosts (about 400) to get some information from the systems. most of them have ssh keys so no problem there. Only a handful don't have ssh keys and come back with a password. Now I want to detect when I'm asked for a password, kill the ssh process and continue to the next host.

here's the code for the ssh part

```
def get_os_info(hostname, command, user=None):
remote = "%s" % hostname if user is None else "%s@%s" %(user, hostname)
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", remote, command],
                       shell=False,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
if result == []:
    error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
    print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
    return None
else:
    return result
```

I am not able to use paramiko.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using trying to detect for a password, instead avoid prompting for it, look at Batch Mode (with Open SSH):

```
ssh -oBatchMode=yes
```

Which is designed to prevent prompting for passwords when calling from scripts. Now you just need to detect if connected or not.

(although, as your comment at the bottom suggest, using paramiko is probably technically better solution)

Comment: I changed the ssh part to:
    ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "-o BatchMode=yes", remote, command],
                       shell=False,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
and that worked. Thanks